# How to use TimeUnit in Java

Tags: java, exception, time, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to use `TimeUnit` in Java but it just sends me errors.
This is how I wrote it:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit ;

public class Anything { 
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. In general when you ask us about errors _you_ get you should tell us what errors those are and provide as many details as possible (e.g. exact message, stacktraces etc.).

Comment: Capitalisation is relevant in Java. Start by copying a working `main` class, making sure you keep the capitalisation of keywords like `import`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this as your code have many `syntax errors` as well as you are not `handling Exception` during the call of `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);`, either use throws or surround this with try catch.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit ;

public class Anything { 
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hi");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a version problem. It's work in jdk17

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).